# How broadcast receiver works in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a question about BroadcastReceiver in Android, say, about system broadcast receiver `BOOT_COMPLETED`. If I have written a listener to Broadcast after system is booted and installed it. How the android system would know that it has to notify my application, since my application is not running but just installed? Is it that, all BroadcastReceiver derived classes are always in the memory (or system loads them in the memory after bootup) and whenever any broadcast happens, all relevant application can receive it.

Thanks
Braj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the broadcast BOOT_COMPLETED is sent, the Android system checks the manifests of loaded apps to see if anything is meant to handle that message. The same is true for implicit intents, and all broadcasts.

Manifests are public facing and allows the system to know what your app can and will do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does it mean that all the Manifests are always in the memory? This is because, once we install any app, it will goto storage.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate.  The manifest file is parsed and registered with the Android system when an application is installed.  No file operations actually happen when an intent is sent, rather, internal data structures built from the parsed manifests are examined.